# Actualizar listas dentro de diccionarios

Tags: python, array, arraylist

Luego de pedir los votos de las mascotas, ¿como esos nuevos datos los actualizo en la lista votos?

```
mascotas={'Puka':[0,0,0],'Morita':[0,0,0],'Martin':[0,0,0],'Napo':[0,0,0]}
redesSociales=['Facebook','Instagram','Twitter']

votos = list(mascotas.keys())
arreglo = np.array(votos)
valores = list(mascotas.values())
arreglo1 = np.array(valores)

for nombre in mascotas:
    for i in range(len(redesSociales)):
        matriz = input("Ingrese votos obtenidos para %s en %s:" % (nombre,redesSociales[i])).isdigit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error en la lectura del dato, ya que `isdigit()` te retorna un *booleano* que vale `True` si lo que introdujo el usuario está formado por dígitos, o `False` si no, pero no te devuelve el entero como quizás tú pensabas. Para eso debes hacer `int()` sobre el valor devuelto por `input()`.

Una vez has leido el dato correctamente, el introducirlo en la lista correspondiente es muy sencillo, ya que en `mascotas[nombre]` tienes la lista correspondiente a esa mascota, y en el elemento `[i]`  de esa lista es donde debes meter el valor leido.

Por tanto (he eliminado las dependencias de numpy, pues no las usas para nada en el resto del código y por tanto no están relacionadas con lo que preguntas):

```
mascotas={'Puka':[0,0,0],'Morita':[0,0,0],'Martin':[0,0,0],'Napo':[0,0,0]}
redesSociales=['Facebook','Instagram','Twitter']

for nombre in mascotas:
    for i in range(len(redesSociales)):
        voto = input("Ingrese votos obtenidos para %s en %s:" % (nombre,redesSociales[i]))
        voto = int(voto)
        mascotas[nombre][i] = voto
```

Tras ejecutar este código y dar como respuesta valores correlativos entre 1 y 12, si imprimes la variable `mascotas` observarás:

```
{'Puka': [1, 2, 3], 'Morita': [4, 5, 6], 'Martin': [7, 8, 9], 'Napo': [10, 11, 12]}
```

**Pequeña mejora**.

En el bucle interno en que iteras sobre `i`, necesitamos este índice `i` para poder acceder a `mascotas[nombre][i]`, pero también necesitamos el nombre de la red social `redesSociales[i]` para usarlo en el mensaje de `input()`.

La función `enumerate(lista)` te devuelve en cada iteración el valor del índice, y el valor del elemento. Esto te evita tener que usar `range(len())` y tener que acceder a `redesSociales[i]` dentro del bucle, quedando más legible y más *pythónico*:

```
for nombre in mascotas:
    for i, red in enumerate(redesSociales):
        votos = input("Ingrese votos obtenidos para %s en %s:" % (nombre,red))
        votos = int(votos)
        mascotas[nombre][i] = votos
```

### Mejora en estructura de datos

En lugar de que `mascotas` sea un diccionario ya preparado para guardar los votos que vayas leyendo, sería mejor que simplemente fuese la lista con los nombres de las mascotas.

El tener que escribir todos esos `[0,0,0]` "a mano" no  parece buena idea ¿Y si aumentas el número de redes sociales a cuatro? Tendrías que cambiar todas esas listas iniciales.

Parece mejor solución ir construyendo esas listas a medida que lees los datos. Te planteo las siguientes modificaciones:

- `mascotas` es puramente una lista de nombres
- `votos` será el diccionario cuyas claves serán las mascotas y cuyos valores serán las listas de votos, pero ese diccionario se va construyendo dinámicamente a medida que se leen los datos. Inicialmente está vacío.

Este sería el código (donde ya no es necesario usar `enumerate()` porque no accedemos a elementos de las listas por su índice):

```
mascotas = ['Puka', 'Morita', 'Martin','Napo']
redesSociales = ['Facebook','Instagram','Twitter']

votos = {}

for nombre in mascotas:
    # Crear una lista de votos vacía para esta mascota
    votos[nombre] = []
    for red in redesSociales:
        voto = input("Ingrese votos obtenidos para %s en %s:" % (nombre,red))
        # Añadir este voto a la lista de esta mascota
        votos[nombre].append(int(voto))
```